# C++ library for simple image manipulations

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm currently using openCV for some image reading, filtering and resizing.

However, openCV support a whole other bunch of functionality and is much too big for my taste. I'm looking for something much smaller or more dedicated (.so should be a few measly 10Ks).

Any recommendation on other libraries or home-brew projects?

The list of classes and functions I use is:

```
cv::Mat
cv::filter2D
cv::Point
cv::Rect
cv::Size
cv::MinMaxLoc
cv::resize
cv::Size
cv::Split
cv::Vec3f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) provides just about all of the above, some under different names, and as well as the command line program there are bindings for various languages including C++ with [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php).

Answer (score 0):

LibVips
https://github.com/libvips/libvips

And leptonica
http://www.leptonica.com/

Will have the functionaity you need. Not sure about their final size, though;.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: thanks. Updated.  

(dear stackexchange readers: _do that_ - a single comment now and then can keep answers up-to-date and alive.)